# Importing json file throws error in my Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import

I'm trying to create my first vue plugin package but I'm having an issue in reading the JSON file in the vue component.

When I pull the plugin, it throws this error below.
I'm sure I'm not doing everything well but don't know where.

[image: import error]

```
<script>
import states from './data.json'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            states: states
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the link to the code [git hub repo](https://github.com/Cejowisz/vue-nigeria-states-lgas)

Thanks guys in advance.

I have also added below code in the loaders array, still not working

```
       {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your GitHub repo doesn't match your screenshot: there's no `start` script, and running `build` does not emit the mentioned error.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using it another project @tony19

Comment: so update your question

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I have updated.

Comment: check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/7349pjz200), it works fine

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I have checked it. I have also tried to use babel loader still not working.

Comment: you are using old versions of webpack and vue.js, try to create your project using vue cli 3